# error while running spring boot app on localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to run my spring boot applicationon localhost ,normally i should get Whitelabel error page for the first time,but i got this error while running it.

```
    ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: show your application properties configuration.

Comment: it's a new springboot project, i have changed just the server port in my application.priperties file like this  server.port=9090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in your log, you try to run the application without providing information about the database.

Spring and Spring-boot are not entirely based on magic.

- They can guess some database information, like the `url` if you use an embedded datasource (as mentioned in the log you provided). Have this dependency on your classpath if you want to run your application with an in-memory database:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Make sure there is not the `<scope>test</scope>` in this dependency. And, at runtime, `spring-boot` will automatically connect to your `hsqldb` database.

- If you are running your application and you have a production oriented database, like PostgreSQL for instance, then `spring-boot` can't guess what is the connection information, like the `url` or the database name. And you have to provide this properties in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<database_host>:<port>/<database_name>
spring.datasource.username=myUser
spring.datasource.password=secret
spring.datasource.type= (Not necessary)
```

If you don't provide that, it's like posting a mail without giving any adresses... you can't find the person you are looking for.

Hope it helps !

Comment: if it worked for you, mark the answer as so. It might help others. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the log depicts, you have to review your data-source configs, and make sure all good.

Comment: normally it should run without adding configurations concerning database or something else.